# How to change the type of data from [[, , , ,]] to [[],[],[]]?

Tags: python, arrays

is there any way to change the type of data?

In order to fit the model(or you can say function) that I'm using currently, I need to input a data type that is array of array, like this.

[image]

My current data looks like this.

[image]

Just some simple codes here.

```py
#The code they provide(which is an arbitary one)
arr = 440.0 * np.ones([1, 10, 1], dtype=np.float32)

#My current one you can just go through a loop
arr_lst = []
for i in range(10):
    arr_lst.append(i)
arr_lst
```

Comment: Do you want an actual numpy array, like the provided code produces? Or do you want a list of lists? Those two data structures support different operations, and they can both be useful, just for different things.

Comment: "The code they provide" and "My current one" do two completely different things. What do you want actually want here?

Comment: "My current data" has a list which contains one or more numpy arrays. Don't mix these data structures like this. It looks like you have a 1D array that you want to turn into a 2D array. Most likely you need to just call [`np.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with appropriate parameters.

Comment: @Blckknght I want array, but convert list to array I don't think there's a problem.(Not sure)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OMG, that's very messy. I think your comprehension is right. BTW, I've tried reshape, but I found that the data type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. But the expected type is `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @Megan If you want help with that error, you will need to show the code that causes it. And yes, mixxing lists and numpy arrays like you are is incredibly messy and difficult to keep straight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
arr = 440.0 * np.ones([1, 1, 1], dtype=np.float32)

#My current one you can just go through a loop
arr_lst = []
for i in range(10):
    arr_lst.append(i)

#Try list comprehension
[[x] for x in list(arr_lst)]
```

Ouput:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can `reshape` after changing `arr_lst` to numpy array

```
arr_lst = [i for i in range(10)]
arr = np.array(arr_lst).reshape(1, len(arr_lst), 1)
print(arr)
```

Output

```
[[[0]
  [1]
  [2]
  [3]
  [4]
  [5]
  [6]
  [7]
  [8]
  [9]]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I think it's almost there. However, I found that the data type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` in your answer. But their type is `numpy.ndarray`. Could you fix it, I appreciate it

Comment: @Megan those are the same thing.

Comment: Really? But it can't fit the function successfully

Comment: @Megan what do you mean by that? what function? what is the issue?